# How do I apply a traffic limit to those connecting from a specific port with iptables or tc?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, iptables

To my CentOS server, TCP connection is provided over port 643 and UDP connection is provided over port 6194. I want to add 1 hour drop rule to each IP address that consumes 50MB traffic from each of these ports.

Can I do this using `iptables` or `tc`? If I can how do I do it? I don't know enough about the subject, can you help me please?

Comment: Since you are just looking for a tool or how to use it and the question is mostly not about programming, you may find question and answers easier at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [limit incoming and outgoing bandwidth and latency](https://serverfault.com/questions/507658/l) with `tc` ([Traffic Control](https://wiki.debian.org/TrafficControl)). This means you can control the throughput, the data amount over time only.

According your description for 50MB/hr you would need to set something like 125kBps for your `rate`. Since it is bandwidth limitation to make sure that only a specific amount of traffic can be used, there is no time limitation.

**Further Questions and Answers** on this topic are

- [Limiting interface bandwidth with `tc`](https://serverfault.com/questions/452829/)
- [Limit network bandwith for an IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/174010/)
- [How to limit network bandwidth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/)

A more **Advanced Solution** could be

- [Rate limit network but allow bursting per TCP connection before limiting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229403/)

Even if it is possible to cut of TCP/IP connections via in example `cutter` tool or [set block time with `iptables`](https://superuser.com/questions/814739/), I am not aware of any production ready solution for controlling the time of a network session. You may also have a look into `wondershaper` or `trickle`.